# Making LaTex Lists Wrap

Tags: formatting, latex

So I have the following LaTex list, and many like it in a paper I'm translating:

```
\begin{enumerate} 
\item If $\mathfrak{E}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$ with the arguments $x, y, z$ a solution of the Maxwell's equations (1), then through the components $\mathfrak{E}_x, \mathfrak{E}_y, \mathfrak{-E}_z, \mathfrak{-B}_x, \mathfrak{-B}_y, \mathfrak{B}_z$, with the arguments $x, y, z$ is given also an electromagnetic field that is a solution to Maxwell's equations.
\item If $\mathfrak{E, B}$ is the electromagnetic field of a planar electromagnetic wave radiation, then $\mathfrak{E}_x, \mathfrak{E}_y, \mathfrak{B}_z$ are symmetrical to the plane of the figure with $\mathfrak{E}_z, \mathfrak{B}_x, \mathfrak{B}_y$, with opposite values.
\item If $\mathfrak{E, B}$ a solution to Maxwell's equations (1), the following field is as well:
$$\mathfrak{E'} = \pm \sqrt{\frac{\mu}{\epsilon}} \mathfrak{B}, \mathfrak{B'} = \mp \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{\mu}} \mathfrak{E}$$
\end{enumerate}\par
```

It compiles to this:

[image]

There's a lot of dead space that should be taken up by text. How do I make the text wrap around the numbers?

PS. Also, I'm trying to add space between the equations. Simply putting more spaces didn't do it. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange how you want to save space in the enumeration yet add space between equations. I enjoy the current display. However, you can use a custom `mylist` which looks like an `enumerate` without alignment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}% Just for this example
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\newenvironment{mylist}
  {\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% No paragraph indent
   \setcounter{enumi}{0}% Restart enumeration at level 1 (i)
   \renewcommand{\item}{\par\refstepcounter{enumi}%
   \theenumi.~\ignorespaces}%
  }{}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  If~$\mathfrak{E}$ and~$\mathfrak{B}$ with the arguments~$x$, $y$,~$z$ a solution of the Maxwell's equations~(1), 
  then through the components~$\mathfrak{E}_x$, $\mathfrak{E}_y$, $\mathfrak{-E}_z$, $\mathfrak{-B}_x$, 
  $\mathfrak{-B}_y$,~$\mathfrak{B}_z$, with the arguments~$x$, $y$,~$z$ is given also an electromagnetic field 
  that is a solution to Maxwell's equations.

  \item
  If~$\mathfrak{E}$, $\mathfrak{B}$ is the electromagnetic field of a planar electromagnetic wave radiation, 
  then~$\mathfrak{E}_x$, $\mathfrak{E}_y$,~$\mathfrak{B}_z$ are symmetrical to the plane of the figure 
  with~$\mathfrak{E}_z$, $\mathfrak{B}_x$,~$\mathfrak{B}_y$, with opposite values.

  \item
  If~$\mathfrak{E}$, $\mathfrak{B}$ a solution to Maxwell's equations~(1), the following field is as well:
  \[
    \mathfrak{E'} = \pm \sqrt{\frac{\mu}{\epsilon}} \mathfrak{B}, \mathfrak{B'} = 
      \mp \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{\mu}} \mathfrak{E}
  \]
\end{enumerate}

\begin{mylist}
  \item
  If~$\mathfrak{E}$ and~$\mathfrak{B}$ with the arguments~$x$, $y$,~$z$ a solution of the Maxwell's equations~(1), 
  then through the components~$\mathfrak{E}_x$, $\mathfrak{E}_y$, $\mathfrak{-E}_z$, $\mathfrak{-B}_x$, 
  $\mathfrak{-B}_y$,~$\mathfrak{B}_z$, with the arguments~$x$, $y$,~$z$ is given also an electromagnetic field 
  that is a solution to Maxwell's equations.

  \item
  If~$\mathfrak{E}$, $\mathfrak{B}$ is the electromagnetic field of a planar electromagnetic wave radiation, 
  then~$\mathfrak{E}_x$, $\mathfrak{E}_y$,~$\mathfrak{B}_z$ are symmetrical to the plane of the figure 
  with~$\mathfrak{E}_z$, $\mathfrak{B}_x$,~$\mathfrak{B}_y$, with opposite values.

  \item
  If~$\mathfrak{E}$, $\mathfrak{B}$ a solution to Maxwell's equations~(1), the following field is as well:
  \[
    \mathfrak{E'} = \pm \sqrt{\frac{\mu}{\epsilon}} \mathfrak{B}, \mathfrak{B'} = 
      \mp \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{\mu}} \mathfrak{E}
  \]
\end{mylist}

\end{document}
```

For changing the spacing around display equations, see [How can I decrease spaces between equations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32918/5764) Also see [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$` … `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764)

Comment: Thank you, have not yet learned how to define items. Saving space on equations is pointless, as the empty space will not get filled by anything else so might as well add something between them.